# Include blade file from another file not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to include this comments.index file:

```
@extends('posts.show')

@section('title', 'Comments')

@section('comments')
<a href="{{route('comments.create', ['id'=>$post->id])}}">Create Comment</a>
    @foreach ($comments as $comment)
        @if ($comment->post_id == $post->id)
        <div class="border margin mb-1">
            <div class="border margin">
                <p>{{$comment->text}}</p>
            </div>
            <a href="{{route('comments.edit', $comment->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary float-end">Edit</a>
        </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
<a href="{{route('posts.show', ['id'=>$post->id])}}">Back</a>
@endsection
```

From this posts.show file:

```
@extends('layouts.myapp')
@section('content')

<head>
   <link href="{{ asset('css/posts.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<div class="post_container">
   <div id="post_title">
     {{$post->title}}
   </div>
   <div id="post_text">
      {{$post->text ?? 'Empty'}}
   </div>
   <div>
      <img src="{{ asset('storage/images/'. $post->image) }}">
      <p>
        {{$post->image}}
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
   <h2>Comments</h2>
   <div>
     @include('comments')
   </div>
   <a href="{{route('comments.index', ['id' => $post->id])}}">Comments</a>
</div>
<a href="{{route('welcome')}}">Back</a>

@endsection
```

Now the issue is that when I include 'comments' it throws 'view comments not found' error and asks if I am sure there is a blade file with such a name. This made me think that I need to include 'comments.index', but when I do this I get 'undefined variable $comments' error.

Comment: so you need to pass `comments and post` variable to comment file when include

Comment: I've tried to pass both variables but I get an undefined page while no data is being passed

Comment: Doesn't `$comments` need to be `$post->comments` (I guess that relation is defined on the post model) In that case, your if statement on post_id is not needed either.

Comment: side note: `<a href="{{route('comments.index', ['id' => $post->id])}}">Comments</a>` will link to the same page in this case

Answer (score 0):

Doing an include of a partial is dot notation. So in this example...

```
@include( 'includes.modals.dude' )
```

This is really located in views -> includes -> modals -> dude.blade.php

The file name must be YourName.blade.php.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are providing a relative path, include directive needs absolute path. So, in your case following code should work.

```
@include('comments.index')
```

Comment: It's not passing a path at all, it's a view name.

Comment: @include('comments') tries to find comments.blade.php in views folder. But his file is in comments/index.blade.php So, @include('comments.index) should be used.